# Как передать пароль и логин в web форму?

Tags: iwebbrowser2

1. Подскажите, как передать с помощью WebBrowser в Internet Explorer значение логина и пароля, а затем программо нажать на кнопку их ввода.
2. Подскажите, как считать нужные данные с загруженной web страницы.

Answer (score 3):

Код для получения информации из элемента с указанным именем и помещение ее в переменную

```
s:=form1.WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('имя нужного элемента').value;
```

Код для помещения данных в объект с указанным именем

```
form1.WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('имя нужного объекта').value:='то, что хотите туда поставить';
```

Если объект не имеет имени, то например таким вот образом можно нажать кнопку submit

```
for i := 0 to webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.Item(0).elements.Length - 1 do
if (webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.Item(0).elements.Item(i).type='submit')  then
webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.Item(0).elements.Item(i).click;
```

Во всех случаях Вам необходимо сначала выяснить какие имена у интересующих Вас элементов html-страницы. Для этого откройте исходный код html-документа и найдите эти элементы. Вам нужно значение их атрибута ID, или NAME. В последнем случае замените в коде Delphi вместо 
GetElementByID - GetElementByName

Comment: GetElementByID!!!!!! не GetElementByNAME а именно GetElementByID
поэтому нужно использовать не свойство name элемента, а свойство id

Comment: В принципе, можно и тот и тот способ, но сейчас большинство людей используют GetElementByID